# Why useEffect causing infinite rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect, use-state

I have a Rooms component which I want to re-render when the filtering settings for the room changes.The useEffect hook for the same is:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        var items1=items.filter((item)=>{
            if(item.fields.price<=price)
            return item;
        })
        var items2=items1.filter((item)=>{
            if(item.fields.breakfast==breakfast)
            return item;
        })
        var items3=items2.filter((item)=>{
            if(item.fields.pets==petsAllowed)
            return item;
        })
        var items4=items3.filter((item)=>{
            if(item.fields.capacity<=capacity)
            return item;
        })
        filteredRooms=items4;
        if(items4.length!=items.length)
        setFilteredRooms(items4);
    })
```

I havent added filteredRooms as a dependency but still its causing infinte re-rendering.

Comment: FWIW, `items4!=items` will always be `true` because `.filter` *always* returns a new array.

Comment: Because you're changing state in an effect that runs on every state change.

Comment: @FelixKling I have now checked the lengths of the arrays ,still its running an infinite loop.

Comment: is there another useEffect hook in your code? also do you have any other state updates in your useEffect hook? any form of state updates can cause a rerender. Moreover , if your state is "filteredRooms" you cannot reassign it to items4 because state is immutable

Comment: You probably don't want to keep the filtered items in the state but rather use `useMemo` to compute the filtered array from the respective input.

Answer (score 2):

When using useEffect without an array of dependencies it will be executed whenever some state changes. And your array comparison `if(items4!=items)` always returns `true`. So the state is always updated. This generates the loop.

Try something like:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    var items1=items.filter((item)=>{
        if(item.fields.price<=price)
        return item;
    })
    var items2=items1.filter((item)=>{
        if(item.fields.breakfast==breakfast)
        return item;
    })
    var items3=items2.filter((item)=>{
        if(item.fields.pets==petsAllowed)
        return item;
    })
    var items4=items3.filter((item)=>{
        if(item.fields.capacity<=capacity)
        return item;
    })
    filteredRooms=items4;
    if(items4.equals(items))
    setFilteredRooms(items4);
},[])
```

Comment: I have now changed my code by comparing the lengths of the arrays ,still its causing an infinite re-render.

Comment: what if the developer wants to update the filteredRooms ... this solution only doesnt rerender because it happens OnMount hence your empty dependency array

Comment: What's this `.equals` function?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Rooms component which I want to re-render when the filtering settings for the room changes.

There is likely not a reason to store the filtered array in state. Instead you should be using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), but if `items` is small you could also just compute the filtered array directly in the render function.

Also there is no need to call `.filter` multiple times, once is enough.

```
const filteredRooms = useMemo(
  () => items.filter(
    ({fields}) => fields.price === price && 
                  fields.breakfast === breakfast &&
                  fields.pets === petsAllowed &&
                  fields.capacity <= capacity
  ),
  [items, price, breakfast, petsAllowed, capacity]
)
// use filteredRooms as needed
```

This will update `filteredRooms` whenever `items`, `price`, `breakfast`, `petsAllowed` or `capacity` changes.